# Performing QField data import?

Tags: qgis, import, qfield

When I try to bring fieldwork back to my desktop, QField seems to be asking for an import folder. Exploring the problem a little, it seems like folks copy/paste their field work data into an existing folder on their home computer, rather than using the import folder.

Could someone please explain the steps/workflow for getting fieldwork updates off my mobile device and back into the QGIS project?

Comment: What are the precise and detailed steps that you have tried?

Comment: I looked for an auto created import folder, couldn't find it. Tried to create an import folder, and qfield wouldn't recognize  or use it. Then I copied the files from my phone export folder to the computers export folder, and when I brought those files to the qgis project, I couldn't find the changes I made. So I'm obviously approaching this whole workflow wrong, and I cant quite see why